# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory # include <Python.h>

Tags: tensorflow, path, header, bazel

I receive the following error:

```
bazel-out/k8-py2-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.cc:171:21: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 # include <Python.h>
```

I tried the following but still receive the same error:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev 

export PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include/python2.7"
```